# How to limit the cpu usage of Mathematica?

Tags: parallelization, map

I am runing mathematica with `ParallelMap[]`, on a win10 computer with 8 physical cores.

**The cpu usage always rocks up to 100%, though `LaunchKernels[4]` is applied in the first place. It remains 100%, even though I only use `Map[]` without Parallel.**

I have tried to configurethe parallel preferences, but nothing changes.

Could somebody help me out?

**Detials of my codes**

It's about energy mimization method. A energy funciton `P=P[a1,a2,a3,a4;q]` is predefined **without any hold**, where `{a1,a2,a3,a4}` are the unkonwn variables, and `q` is a sweeping parameter. The code is somthing like this,

```
nq=Range[0,10,0.01];
eqs={(D[P, a1]) == 0, (D[P, a2]) == 0, (D[P, a3]) ==   0, (D[P, a4]) == 0};
so[s_]:=NSolve[eqs /. q -> s, {a1,a2,a3,a4}, Reals] // FullSimplify;
sos=ParallelMap[so,nq]
```

**When** use `Map[]` without parallel running,

[image: Map[]]

**When** use `ParallelMap[]` following `LaunchKernels[4]`

[image: ParallelMap[] following LaunchKernels[4]]

Comment: Some of the built-in functions like Dot[] etc are already parallelized, so it may happen that all cores are used even with just Map. Without a sample code it's hard to tell where the issue occurs.

Comment: One way to stop MMA taking 100% of your cores/time is to run other heavy computational processes at the same time.  On a general purpose o/s such as Windows scheduling 'fairness' should ensure that MMA consumption of cores/time falls below 100%.  I mention this because it's not clear (to me at least) what sort of help you seek.  Do you want a better understanding of how MMA uses the hardware resources it finds itself running on?

Comment: In Win10 Task Manager, under details tab, select the application's exe file, right click and choose Set Affinity to limit the cores that the app can use. This is a hard OS override, not an Mma solution. Another option is Set Priority that you can configure. Also check this tool for configuring limits on memory usage: https://github.com/lowleveldesign/process-governor. It seems that you are running multiple intensive apps on your machine and want to limit resource hogging. Download a temp monitor such as coretemp to keep an eye on the temps. Best of luck.

Comment: @Hans Olo  Hi, Hans. The details of my code is added in my question now. Could you give some advice? thanks.

Comment: It seems the function NSolve[] causes the high cpu usage.

Comment: Why would you want to limit the CPU usage in the first place? As @HighPerformanceMark mentioned, the OS should ensure other applications also get some resources if they need them. Other than that, more CPU usage just means it will be done sooner

Comment: @Lukas Lang Well, I only have one computer, and want to watch streaming media while my computer runs mathematica. But the 100% cpu usage makes the experience a bit bumpy. :P

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I kind of want to know why LaunchKernals[] stops to work.